# How do I get rid of the Blind Bruiser?

Tags: sunless-sea

So, I accepted a gift from a certain legitimate businessman in exchange for doing some favours. It was fun at first but I'm getting sick of delivering Crates of Human Souls all over the zee. I have better things to do.

Unfortunately, the last time I tried to quit, the Blind Bruiser took offence and murdered me. Is there another way to end this questline or, failing that, a way to survive the result of saying no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last time I quit, I had just finished a delivery. Absolutely nothing bad happened, the Blind Bruiser simply bade me farewell (with the requisite threats to keep our previous dealings quiet, of course). I also picked up the quality "Everything is Probably Perfectly All Right", which is a bit disturbing but hasn't had any ill effects yet. (And I've picked up at least 100 "Time, the Healer" since then, so if something was going to go wrong, it would already have gone wrong.)

In short, don't quit when you owe the Blind Bruiser something. Finish a delivery, then refuse the next one.